# How do I translate the data returned by FIBMAP into LBA sectors of the disk?

Tags: c++, linux, file, disk

I need to determine the sector range(s) occupied by a file on a disk device (for Linux). Let's assume it's a simple disk (no RAID) with MBR or GPT partition table.

I learned that I can get the position of a file within the file system using `FIBMAP` ioctl. How do I translate the data returned by `FIBMAP` into LBA sectors of the disk? Thank you

Comment: I suspect this may be filesystem-dependent. Which filesystem(s) do you need to support?

Comment: ext3, ext4 as a minimum. But I would really appreciate a file system independent solution

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to start at the beginning inode and iterate from there? And as the file may be fragmented to each and every block, is it worth the hassle?

Comment: @ott-- sorry I'm not sure what do you mean. Why should I iterate the inodes if I only need to know the position of a single file?

Comment: You wrote `position of a file` in the header and then `the sector range(s) occupied by a file`. I supposed the latter.

Comment: hmm, may be I'm missing something, but whats the difference? I mean file may occupy one or more sector ranges, I need to determine them

Comment: Look at the source code of the hdparm program and look at a bug report here:  http://sourceforge.net/p/hdparm/bugs/58/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer for you but if you look at the source code of hdparm you should be able to figure it out. If you use `hdparm --fibmap /dir1/dir2/foo` it will output the chunks of the file in rows of file offset, start LBA, stop LBA, and sector length. I hope that helps.